# Autolayout Contraints Changes in CollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, autolayout, uicollectionview, pure-layout

I am using PureLayout to create the constraints

in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`

```
if (!_itemDetails){
            _itemDetails = cell.itemDetails;
            _itemDetailsConstraint = [_itemDetails autoPinEdge:ALEdgeBottom toEdge:ALEdgeBottom ofView:cell.imageView];
        }
```

and then in `scrollDidView`

```
float scrollViewHeight = self.collectionView.frame.size.height;
    float scrollOffset = self.collectionView.contentOffset.y;

    if(_itemDetails){

        if (scrollOffset + scrollViewHeight < CGRectGetMaxY(_frontImageView.frame)){

            _itemDetailsConstraint.constant =  CGRectGetMaxY(_frontImageView.frame) - (scrollOffset + scrollViewHeight);

        }
        else{
            _itemDetailsConstraint.constant = 0;
        }
    }

    [_itemDetails.superview layoutIfNeeded];
```

eventhough while debugging, I can see that the constraint's constant changed, the view doesn't update to the new location.

I also tried

```
[self.view layoutIfNeeded]
```

and

```
[self.collectionView layoutIfNeeded]
```

How can I update the view's (`_itemDetails`, which point to a view in a `CollectionViewCell`) location?

Answer (score 0):

```
[collectionView reloadData];
```

if your contraints is create or update in the collection:cellForItemAtIndexPath:,you can reload all cell.